# Remove line character from a text file using Python (With a condition)

Tags: python, character, line

I am new to Stack Overflow site and Python too.

I have a text file which contains transaction of a company with pipe delimiter

There are certain transactions which comes on the second line due to line character.These transactions typically have one more line character in the second line too.

i want to bring the second line and concatenate it with the first line using python.

A sample file given below for my friends to facilitate understanding my issue (Line Numbers are just for our reference purposes):

Line1: A|B|C|D
Line2: A|B|C|
Line3: D
Line4:
Line5: A|B
Line6: C|D
Line7: 
Line8: A|B|C|D

Thanks alot for reading this and for providing the solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you try anything yet? Feed us with some code!

Answer (score 1):

```
while line in fin:
    if line.strip().endswith('|'):
        fou.write(line.strip())
    else:
        fou.write(line)
```

This simple code will do. Assuming `fin, fou` are input and output files you've opened.

If a line ends with `'|'`, new line will be written after `strip()` method which will erase `\n` or any spacing.

Comment: Thanks for this. This would work in my case for sure, however what if the line doesn't end with pipe delimiter and the continuing delimiter is basically on the next line?